# WPF TreeView to Show Only Nodes with a Certain Property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have XAML for my TreeView containing CarNode objects like this.

```
<TreeView x:Name="CARS_TREE" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding CarsTree}" 
      IsEnabled="True" 
      Focusable="False"
      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">

      <!-- handles showing of children, not related to this question -->
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate...>
            ...
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

 </TreeView>
```

**CarsTree** is a collection of CarNode objects

**CarNode** is an object with **IsFiltered** boolean determining if user has filtered for a certain car by enterring some characters in search box.  For example typing in "A" will show all cars having "a" in their model name.

Currently, my TreeView will show all objects in CarsTree regardless whether they are **IsFiltered=true** or not.

Assunming I have following cars in CarsTree collection:
**Audi, Honda, Mazda, Suzuki, VW**

A CarNode object could have subnodes.  For example, **VW** could have **Passat, Golf, Beatle, Tiguan**.  If there is a subnode and use types "**o**" in search field, then both **Golf** and its parent **VW** should be filtered.

How do I ensure

1. if user expands the tree, all cars in CarsTree show  ( It shows all
   cars: **Audi, Honda, Mazda, Suzuki, VW**)
2. if user searches for car by typing "A" or "a", only cars containing
   "a" show in expanded tree (i.e **Audi, Mazda, Honda**)
3. if user types say "**o**" then all cars, including subnodes should
   filter (i.e user enters "**o**" and filtered results are **Honda**, **VW**,
   **Golf**.  Here VW is filtered since it contains Golf.

Comment: You'll have to use something like this: https://www.wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Comment: It works for any collection, the challenge with a treeview is that you'll need a separate collection view source for every set of child nodes.

Comment: sorry but I dont see it working for this situation.  Thanks anyways